# How to use Consul in leader election?

Tags: consul

How do I use Consul to make sure only one service is performing a task?

I've followed the examples in http://www.consul.io/ but I am not 100% sure which way to go. Should I use KV? Should I use services? Or should I use a register a service as a Health Check and make it be callable by the cluster at a given interval?

For example, imagine there are several data centers. Within every data center there are many services running. Every one of these services can send emails. These services have to check if there are any emails to be sent. If there are, then send the emails. However, I don't want the same email be sent more than once.

How would it make sure all emails are sent and none was sent more than once?

I could do this using other technologies, but I am trying to implement this using Consul.

Comment: Sounds like you also need a distributed queue.

Comment: AFAIK: your stated aim can never be achieved with 100% certainty because of network partitioning errors (* where a network is split into two separate networks because a bridge between two clusters of nodes is severed *). Although there are stated solutions even to this problem, I don't think that they are able to guarantee a single leader 100% of the time, which means that you may still end up with multiple messages. You should look at the paxos algorithm and implement it using your tool of choice, although you're better advised to buy a solution rather than build one.

Comment: You may want to read: http://book.mixu.net/distsys/replication.html

Comment: Sounds like an execise in locking. Each server that want to send the emails (assuming there is a central place to look for them) will have to acquire a lock as described in https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/leader-election.html before doing so. As others have mentioned it seems Consul does not provide transactional guarantees.

Making sure each email is actually sent once and removed from the queue is a concern for the email sending service.

The central location/queue for emails to send could be the K/V store, but you might need to enforce locks on updating the K/V store as well.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, would you like to add that as an answer? I read your profile and understand your reasoning, but your answer is the closest to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Point:
The question is how to use Consul to solve a specific problem. However, Consul cannot solve that specific problem because of intrinsic limitations in the nature of a gossip protocol.

When one datacenter cannot talk to another you cannot safely determine if the problem is the network or the affected datacenter.

The usual solution is to define what happens when one DC cannot talk to another one. For example, if we have 3 datacenters (DC1, DC2, and DC3) we can determine that whenever one DC cannot talk to the other 2 DCs then it will stop updating the database.

If DC1 cannot talk to DC2 and DC3 then DC1 will stop updating the database, and the system will assume DC2 and DC3 are still online.

Let's imagine that DC2 and DC3 are still online and they can talk to each other, then we have quorum to continue running the system.

When DC1 comes online again it will play catch up with the database.

Where can Consul help here? It can communicate between DCs and check if they are online... but so can ICMP.

Take a look at the comments. Did this answer your question? Not really. But I don't think the question has an answer.

Second point: The question is "How to use Consul in leader election?" It would have been better to ask how does Consul elect a new leader. Or "Given the documentation in Consul.io, can you give me an example on how to determine the leader using Consul".

If that is what you really want, then the question was already answered: [How does a Consul agent know it is the leader of a cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724519/how-does-a-consul-agent-know-it-is-the-leader-of-a-cluster/27728729#27728729)

Comment: What about https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/leader-election.html ? Also consul supports consistent writes nad CAS (as far as I know) and these should be sufficient for election.

Comment: I think the link provided by @mabn is a good starting point for this. This article/guide describes how to implement client side leader election for a given service within your cluster.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly the use case for [Consul Distributed Locks](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/lock.html)

For example, let's say you have three servers in different AWS availability zones for fail over. Each one is launched with:

```
consul lock -verbose lock-name ./run_server.sh
```

Consul agent will only run the `./run_server.sh` command on which ever server acquires the lock first. If `./run_server.sh` fails on the server with the lock Consul agent will release the lock and another node which acquires it first will execute `./run_server.sh`. This way you get fail over and only one server running at a time. If you registered your Consul health checks properly you'll be able to see that the server on the first node failed and you can repair and restart the `consul lock ...` on that node and it will block until it can acquire the lock.

Currently, Distributed Locking can only happen within a single Consul Datacenter. But, since it is up to you to decide what a Consul Servers make up a Datacenter, you should be able to solve your issue. If you want locking across Federated Consul Datacenters you'll have to wait for it, since it's a roadmap item.