# How does a Consul agent know it is the leader of a cluster?

Tags: consul

In Consul you can have many agents as servers or clients. Amongst all servers one is chosen as the leader. From the agent's point of view, how does it know it is the leader?

Comment: Check this out, this helps you understand it visually.
http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Consul leader is elected via an implementation of the [Raft Protocol](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/consensus.html) from amongst the Quorum of Consul Servers. Only Consul instances that are configured as Servers participate in the Raft Protocol communication. The [Consul Agent](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html) (the daemon) can be started as either a [Client](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/architecture.html) or a [Server](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/servers.html). Only a Server can be the leader of a Datacenter.

The Raft Protocol was created by Diego Ongaro and John Ousterhout from Stanford University in response to the complexity of existing consensus protocols such as [Paxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29). Raft elects a leader via the use of randomized timers. The algorithm is detailed in [Ongaro and Ousterhout's paper](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/wiki/download/attachments/11370504/raft.pdf).

Consul instances that are configured as Clients communicate with the cluster via the [Gossip Protocol](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/gossip.html) which is based on [Serf](https://www.consul.io/intro/vs/serf.html). Serf communication is eventually consistent. The Serf cluster has no central server, each node is considered equal. All nodes (Clients and Servers) in participating the Gossip/Serf Protocol spread messages to their neighbors, which in turn spread messages to their neighbors until the message has propagated to the entire cluster. Sort of like the infection path of a zombie apocalypse. This is done to greatly reduce communication overhead in the cluster as it scales to potentially tens of thousands of nodes.

Consul Clients can forward messages to any Consul Server which will then forward the message to the Leader. Consul Clients do not need to care which Consul Server is the Leader. Only the Servers need to care.

The [Consul HTTP API](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http.html) running on any Consul Server will tell you which Server is the leader at `$ANY_CONSUL_SERVER/v1/status/leader`. However, this has nothing to do with how Consul Agents do leader election.

Comment: I hate to shut down an answer, but the first 5 sentences have nothing to do with the question, while only the 6th one contains the same answer as provided before.

Comment: You asked how an agent knows it's the leader of the cluster. The type of agent has everything to do with narrowing down who can be the leader.

Answer (score 12):

One way is by calling the cluster with `http://<localhost_ip_address>:8500/v1/status/leader`

This will return the current leader. Then just check the IP address returned against the local IP address.

Comment: // , This is how external programs know who is the current leader. But it does not say how that instance of consul itself knows it is the current leader.

Answer (score 6):

`consul operator raft list-peers` also show the relationship between peers;
for example

consul operator raft list-peers

```
Node    ID                                    Address               State     Voter  RaftProtocol
agent1  2a3ae4a0-8193-7da9-f978-911d7df0d184  192.168.110.128:8300  leader    true   3
agent2  5ca6550b-c211-d11f-0236-82a9572e2485  192.168.110.133:8300  follower  true   3
agent3  10e1b43d-9393-6985-242b-8e31411839c5  192.168.110.137:8300  follower  true   3
```

Comment: Operator "raft" subcommand failed: Unexpected response code: 403 (rpc error: Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

It will list the result in the consul group by executing "consul info" command [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbJOX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Consul uses RAFT Consensus Algorithm.
This link below helps you understand how raft works visually (Which also shows how a member is elected as leader step by step).

## http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/

Reference is from official consul documentation: https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/consensus.html